# Dgrid issue with ColumnResizer extension

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm using dgrid with the column resizer extension. I'm also explicitly giving the columns a `width` of `100`  as described in [Additional Column Definition Properties](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/dev-0.4/doc/components/extensions/ColumnResizer.md#additional-column-definition-properties).

The problem is that if the total width of all columns is less than the view port, the columns are not rendered correctly. See image below. After resizing the window or the parent (`BorderContainer`), the columns snap back into place as show in the bottom half of the image.

I'm not able to post my code or a JSFiddle. What could be causing this and how do I get it to render correctly? I tried calling `resize()` on the parent after adding the grid, but it doesn't seem to help. Note that the problem does not occur if I don't provide an explicit `width` for each column. I'm using dojo 1.10.4 with dgrid 0.4.

[image]

Comment: The issue was solved using the answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184341/why-will-the-headings-in-my-dojo-dgrid-not-appear-unless-i-resize-the-browser . Should I delete this question?